# decipher acronyms for Netapp disk shelf configuration options

Tags: configuration, hard-drive, netapp

I want to know what is the meaning of `-C` and `QS` to understand the difference between these two disk shelf configurations:

```
DSK SHLF,24x450GB,15K,3Gb SAS,IOM3,-C,R5 
DSK SHLF,24x450GB,15K,3Gb SAS,IOM3,QS,R5
```

I've had no luck searching for the key to decipher those acronyms and I've searched through both the netapp site itself and via google.

A bonus to you if you not only know what these stand for, but can point to an authoritative reference for this and other Netapp acronyms.

Comment: If someone does answer this, what does PB and PBR mean also?

Comment: In what context did you encounter PB and PBR? Also in disk shelf configuration? Without a context an acronym could take on myriad meanings... I don't know about PB, but I would guess PBR stands for "Policy Based Routing"... or Pabst Blue Ribbon... which reminds me of this quote: ["PBR: Sure it’s watery and tastes like piss, but at least it’s not policy-based routing"](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2011/11/07/openflow-overlords/) (scroll down to 
Flow Routing (Layer 4)). heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked around at one of our resellers and discovered the answer:

```
C - Configured w/system
QS - Quoted separate (a la carte)
```

Also note that it is just `C` and not `-C`. The confusion about that was due to the original part number used incorrectly in the description field of the quote, so:

```
DSK SHLF,24x450GB,15K,3Gb SAS,IOM3,-C,R5
```

should be:

```
DSK SHLF,24x450GB,15K,3Gb SAS,IOM3,C,R5
```

Answer (score 6):

aculich's answer solves the `C` and `QS` mystery.  For more general reference, what remains here is an exhaustive list of all known NetApp acronyms, that grew out of my attempt to answer this question.

Authoritative sources appear to be internal to NetApp, or at least require NetApp support access.  There are, however, publicly available repostings of the Visio/PDF documents called **NetApp Hardware Universe** documents. Here are [two](http://communities.netapp.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/2330-102-1-2633/Hardware%20Universe.pdf) [examples](http://contourds.com/uploads/file/HardwareUniverse%20Resource%20Tab%20NetappProducts.pdf).

There is a NetApp tech note (#020) that says to use the undocumented `sysconfig -ca` command, which displays detailed part numbers.  This may be of some use.

For a while, I thought that `-C` and `QS` were mutually exclusive, but I found some NetApp part numbers (like X267A-QS-R5-C) that seem to incorporate both `-C` and `QS`.

Because I could not find a full list, here's a stub of one that others can contribute to.  I'm including all the ones included in the documentation that I surveyed, even if they are non-NetApp-specific.

First, the ones that are probably NetApp-specific, or have NetApp-specific meanings:

- C - Configured with system
- Cu – Copper Connector
- DC - parts using DC power (an absence of "DC" = AC power)
- EOA – End of Availability
- EOS – End of Support
- ESH – Electronically Switched Hub (there are ESH2, ESH3, ESH4)
- HA - High Availability
- IOM3 - I/O Module, 3 Gbit/sec
- IOM6 - I/O Module, 6 Gbit/sec
- MC - MetroCluster
- NVRAM - Non-Volatile RAM adapters (there are NVRAM1 through NVRAM8)
- Op – Optical (connector)
- PB - ?
- PBR - ?
- QS - Quoted separate (a la carte)
- R5 - appears to be a universal suffix for many types of parts.
- R6 - Ditto. (Maybe R5 vs R6 are generations?)
- SFE - S Family Edition (version sub-variants of Data ONTAP)
- SK - Spares Kit

And here are the more general terms:

- BTU – British Thermal Unit
- FAS – Fabric-Attached Storage
- FC - Fibre Channel
- FC (Op) - Ferrule Connector
- GbE - Gigabit Ethernet
- HSSDC – High-Speed Serial Data
- IB - InfiniBand
- IB4X - InfiniBand 4X
- LC – Lucent Connector
- LRC – Loop Resiliency Circuit
- LUN - Logical Unit Number
- MTP - Mechanical Transfer Pull-Off
- MT-RJ - Mechanical Transfer Registered Jack
- NIC - Network Interface Card
- PDU - Power Distribution Unit
- PSU - Power Supply Unit
- QSFP - Quad Small Form-factor Pluggable (optical connector module)
- SAS – Serial-attached SCSI
- SATA – Serial ATA
- SC - Subscriber Connector
- ST - Straight Tip Connector
- RPM – Revolutions Per Minute
- SFP - Small Form-factor Pluggable (optical connector module)
- VAC - Volts Alternating Current
- VDHCI - Very High Density Cable Interconnect
- VTL – Virtual Tape Library

For reference, here are examples of actual part numbers that use the mystery tokens:

- DS2246-1007-12S-PB-R5-C
- DS2246-1007-12S-PBR-R5-C
- DS2246-1007-12S-QS-R5
- DS2246-1007-12S-R5-C

Comment: well, this is a good start, but doesn't fully answer the question...

Comment: Agreed - apologies for not finding a better one yet.  I haven't given up! I am also hoping that this can become a more general reference, and didn't want my research to go to waste. :-)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Providing a Netapp rosetta stone would be handy for people.